# Holes or Gaps detection in 3D model

Tags: 3d-reconstruction, open3d, pyvista, trimesh

How to detect holes or gaps due to incomplete data in mesh file?

I have tried using several library such as open3d, trimesh, pyvista but unable to fully come with a code that solve problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be a lot more specific if you expect to get an answer. "Detect holes in mesh file" is already ill-defined, especially when we add "due to incomplete data". Meshes can be all kinds. So can holes and gaps. You'll have to narrow down the problem you're trying to solve, otherwise your question is [hopelessly too broad and unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andras, I have a 3d model of a surface which is perfectly carved as a reference. Now, I am making another 3d model of the same surface. But this model is not as complete as the reference model. How to detect such problem.